# How to draw vertical text using canvas.drawParagraph in Flutter

Tags: flutter, canvas

I want to draw vertical text directly using canvas, but I didn't find such methods,

I only found related parameter **TextDirection**, but it only support left--right or right--left.

Here is my code:

```
void drawMeasurementTag(Canvas canvas, Rect limitRect) {
  String text = "this is content";
  double textFont = 18;
  double textWidth = getTextPainter(text, textFont).width;
  Paragraph paragraph = getTextBuilder(
      text, textFont, Colors.red);
  paragraph.layout(ParagraphConstraints(width: textWidth));
  tagPos =Offset(0,0) ;
  canvas.drawParagraph(paragraph, tagPos);

}

ui.Paragraph getTextBuilder(String text, double textFont, Color color) {
  Paint paint = Paint();
  paint.color = getTagBackgroundColor();
  var builder = ui.ParagraphBuilder(ui.ParagraphStyle(
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    fontSize: textFont,
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    maxLines: 1,
  ));
  builder.pushStyle(
    ui.TextStyle(
        color: color,
        textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
        background: paint),
  );
  builder.addText(text);
  ui.Paragraph paragraph = builder.build();

  return paragraph;
}
```

this is what I want to achieve:
[image]
`

Comment: you have to `rotate()` your canvas (or `transform()` for more generic  case)

Comment: thanks, canvas.rotate(pi / 180 * 90); works for me.

Comment: `translate()` + `rotate()` + `translate()` can be replaced with single `transform()`, see https://gist.github.com/pskink/bc6e9112b52a73df69a2315945758c42

Answer (score 0):

You can **rotate your widgets** in flutter by math package:

```
import 'dart:math' as math;
```

Then use this to rotate by 90 degrees:

```
Transform.rotate(
  angle: -math.pi / 2, // edit this angle 
  child: Card(
      child: Text("Rotated text"),
  ),
)
```

Comment: thanks,  for widgets it works well, but I just have to draw everything on canvas, I figured it out with these codes:
    canvas.translate(tagPos.dx, tagPos.dy);
      canvas.rotate(pi / 180 * 90);
      canvas.translate(-tagPos.dx, -tagPos.dy);
      canvas.drawParagraph(paragraph, tagPos);
      canvas.restore();